# Entity Framework - OnModelCreating with Model First

Tags: entity-framework-4, dbcontext

I have a Entity Framework model set up with text templates to generate the code. However, one of them creates the `DBContext` containing an `OnModelCreating`.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
```

How do expand on this, since a partial class with the same override does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `OnModelCreating` when using model first (EDMX). `OnModelCreating` is only for scenarios without using EDMX.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your problem is that the connection string you're using is a standard SQL Server one rather than the Entity Framework one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5942978/8479).