# Entity framework map column which is not in old database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, mapping

I have table in a new DB which contains column 'Note'. I have old DB with the same table with the same structure which have not column 'Note'.
I changed edmx, I added (mapped) column 'Note' from new DB. But if I want to use edmx in old DB I have error: column doest not exists...

I try to put code to try catch, but without succesfull. Error is outside off try catch.

```
//---new version DB
                try
                {
                    vehicles = entities.Vehicle.Where(v => v.NumPlate == numPlate || v.Note == numPlate);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    vehicles = entities.Vehicle.Where(v => v.NumPlate == numPlate);
                }
                //---old version DB

                foreach (Vehicle vehicle in vehicles) //<------- ERROR
```

How can I resolve?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a version system to know which database you are connecting to?By knowing Versions you can simply write different queries in different cases.

Comment: So, if I understand well, I have to create new entity table with new column and by the version used concrete entity table?

Comment: yes and you need different classes attached to these entities as well. Since I know there is no way that EF supports too different entity table by a single class and implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's kind of an 'hack', but you can choose to `ignore` the `Note` property once you're using the old database.

Look for the `OnModelCreating` method in your `context` class, and replace with:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (this.Database.Connection.Database == "Name_Of_Old_Database")
            modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>().Ignore(x => x.Note);
    }
```

**Update:**

Since you're using `.edmx` for mapping and there's currently no way to modify the mapping in runtime i assume my suggestion was indeed wrong.

I still don't get what are you trying to achieve by using the `try/catch` block, it doesn't matter whether you include the (missing) `Note` field in the query or not, since `Entity Framework` realizes the model is no longer compatible with the database, it will refuse to work with this database altogether.

But 2 points to keep in mind:

- Since you're using `IQueryable`, your `try/catch` is indeed in the wrong place, the exception will be thrown only during `Materialization` (when trying to actually retrieving the data).

  You can materialize the query using the `ToList` method (among others):

  `entities.Vehicle.Where(v => v.NumPlate == numPlate || v.Note == numPlate).ToList()`;

  or move the `try/catch` block to wrap the `foreach` statement.
- You can use `System.Data.Entity.Database.CompatibleWithModel()` method to early determine (upon context initialization for example) whether your model and database can still work together.

Comment: Actualy this is good, but database title is the same. I have one value saved in database which present version of database. So I think can be modified to get value of version and then use hack.

Comment: You can try and differentiate between the databases using anything that `this.Database.Connection` exposes. there must be something different in the connection parameters between the two (if not the database name then the host probably).

Comment: Connection can be very differents it is depend on instalation on computer in customers - therefore I cannot use this property.

Comment: I tried to used, but OnModelCreating is not for EDMX see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189624/entity-framework-onmodelcreating-with-model-first)