# Connection string EF Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I started an application using Entity Framework Code First.
In my Web.config I added the connection string:

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=server\mssqlserver2008;Initial Catalog=dbname;persist security info=True; Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And I received a error when I tried to access my Controller: **CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'**

So, I debugged the code and I found that the attribute "ConnectionString" inside my Context it's different from my Web.config:

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyProject.Models.MyContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE
```

Why the ConnectionString is wrong??

Comment: Take a look on [CREATE DATABASE permission denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231934/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-ef-code-first) question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your EF initialization code, make sure you specify the connection string name like this

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext() : base("MyContext") {}
}
```