# MS ASP MVC tutorial EF DB woes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im trying to work my way through the ASP.net MVC tutorial. Ive made it to the point where I am building a model using Entity Framework (http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller). When I launch the app, and navigate to the movies page, I get the following exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException {"CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'."}
```

This happens invariably even though I have followed the tutorial to the letter.

I thought I would just try pointing to our DB server here by changing the web.config's DefaultConnection element by setting the connectionString attribute to:

`"Data Source=XXXXXX\MSSQLSERVER_2012;Initial Catalog=MarkW-ASPMVC-Proj;Integrated Security=false;username=XXXXX;password=XXXXX;"`

This has zero effect on the state of the application, and I get the same exact exception. I tried a clean, a rebuild all, I even added the DefaultConnection connection string node to both debug and release web.config transforms, but when I inspect the connection at runtime when the exception happens it says its:

```
"Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MvcApplication1.Models.Movie+MovieDBContext;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFrameworkMUE"
```

Where is this coming from? I searched the whole project and none of the occurrences of SQLEXPRESS were in a connection string. What could I have possibly done wrong for the tutorial to just not work in this way, and most importantly... why does EF seemingly ignore the value I have for the default connection string in my web config?

Another Edit: I managed to find a work around for this... feels like more of a hack. I read the documentation for the DbContext type which my context derives from. One of the constructors accepts a connection string, so I figured I could modify the class like so:

```
    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public MovieDBContext() : base(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString)
        {

        }
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
```

This works now... but I still would like to know why I have to do this, and why the EF isn't using web.config values.

Complete stack trace:

`[SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753986
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction) +5296058
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout) +280
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) +405
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +160
   System.Data.SqlClient.<>c__DisplayClassa.<DbCreateDatabase>b__7(SqlConnection conn) +33
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action1 act) +92
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(SqlConnection sqlConnection, Action1 act) +384
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection) +276
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateDatabase() +84
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Utilities.DatabaseCreator.Create(DbConnection connection) +101
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists() +115
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists() +34
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +150
   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update() +33
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +456
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext) +173
   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(Boolean skipExistsCheck) +241
   System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +396
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__6() +67
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action) +110
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization() +273
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.b__4(InternalContext c) +31
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction1.PerformAction(TInput input) +143
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action1 action) +270
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase() +123
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +42
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.Initialize() +137
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet1.GetEnumerator() +38
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +99
   System.Collections.Generic.List1..ctor(IEnumerable1 collection) +369
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable1 source) +58
   MvcApplication1.Controllers.MovieController.Index() in c:\Users\mwolfert\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MvcApplication1\MvcApplication1\Controllers\MovieController.cs:21
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary2 parameters) +435
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2 parameters) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass81.b__7(IAsyncResult _) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +126
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9658668
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155`

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace you receive here please.

Comment: Couple things to check 1. in the connection string I think it should be **user id** and not username. 2. Check your web.config for that connectionstring name DefaultConnection in the section Connectionstrings. 3. Check this link to see if it provides any  insight [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231934/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-ef-code-first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231934/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-ef-code-first)

Comment: You are right about the connection string user id part. Ill look at the link here.