# How to open a password protected SQL Server CE database with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using EF 6.0 and SQL Server CE 4.0. The `.sdf` file is password protected, which I verified by opening the file with LinqPad. When I try to open this database in code with the following connection string, I get an exception:

> The specified password does not match the database password

Code:

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext("ExamManagement"))
{
    context.Database.Initialize(false);
}
```

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ExamManagement" 
         connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Pikeman.sdf;Max Database Size=4091;Password=123;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

[image]
Stack trace:

> at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Comment: You are most likely using a wrong connection string

Comment: please see my updated screen shot. It seems that the connection string is correct but the `Password` part is ignored.

Comment: Are you testing in linqpad against the correct database file? Look in your bin/debug folder - maybe there is a copy of the sdf file there!

Comment: The connection string is pointing to the right sdf file. If I remove the `.sdf` from the target directory, executing the code above will create a new `.sdf` file at the target directory without any exception. However, the newly created database is NOT password protected. Again, it seems that the `Password` part is ignored.

Comment: To see if the issue is EF related, can you try opening ADO.NET connection with the same connection sting from the same code location that is generating the exception. e.g. `context.Database.Connection.Open();` or `new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|Pikeman.sdf;Max Database Size=4091;Password=123;").Open();` and let us know.

Comment: I hope either of 1st 2 answers in the stackoverflow post here might help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231934/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-ef-code-first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection string is OK (usually I don't specify Max Database Size, you can try to delete the parameter but I'm quite sure this is not the problem).
So, in your case, I think you are probably opening a database with a different password (as the exception suggests) or you are opening a wrong database.
Try to specify an absolute path and open the database from that path, for example

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ExamManagement" 
         connectionString="Data Source=C:\temp\Pikeman.sdf;Password=123;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Ok. Found the issue. The problem was the the default DbContext constructor was using a default connection string which is different from the one in the `app.config` file. When the DbMigrationsConfiguration seeds the database, it uses the default connection string without the password, which happens to pointing to the same directory as the `app.config` connection string.