# My database isn't deploying with my MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, publish

After publishing my MVC app, my website is giving me this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I have added the connection string, both in the web.config file and in the ASP.NET settings on the domain, this is the connection string:

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ADB;Integrated Security=True;User ID=MVCU;Password=MVCPASS
```

I have created a database in the domain's server, with the same Username and Password as it is in the connection string above.

The database itself only has the default login/registration tables, that MVC creates automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your connection string "Integrated Security" is set to true. Set it false and try again.

Comment: Thanks, this helped, but I also had to add "./MSSQLSERVER2014" to the initial catalog, and it worked.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a repeat from the question [CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' (EF code-first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231934/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-ef-code-first). But it should also answer your question.

Comment: Yea I had seen that, It doesn't answer my question because the database is created within visual studio, so I don't really know how to access its properties.

Comment: In Visual studio there is a side menu containing the data source, which should also contain your database. there you should be able to access the permissions, If it is a local database. If it is not local database then you will have to set it up on the database itself. Another suggestion is create a new database, Don't use master. Using Master isn't the best practice.