# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' (no admin rights)

Tags: sql-server

I have deleted my database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and wanted to recreate it (I did this often in the past) but then I get the error

> Msg 262, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>
> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

Others who asked this question here got the answer to try running it as admin but I do not have the possibility to do so since my superior (who has the password) is on vacation. Is there any other workaround to create a database? In the past I could create it without admin rights but that was on another server.

Comment: Simply put; no. If you don't have permission to create databases you can't get around it. If permissions could be avoided, they would be meaningless. They are there for a reason, and work the way they do for a reason. You will need to use a login with high enough permission to create a login.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44486065/11683?

Comment: `often in the past` so what changed? Somehow, someone removed that permission from you. `running it as admin` is meaningless - either you connected using an account that has the `CREATE DATABASE` permission or not.

Comment: Time to call your superior from bahamas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the past I could create it without admin rights but that was on
>   another server.

You should open BOL article [CREATE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#permissions) and look at the `permissions` section:

> Requires `CREATE DATABASE`, `CREATE ANY DATABASE`, or `ALTER ANY DATABASE`
>   permission.

So you should have any of the above or be a member of `db_creator` fixed server role. All of the above is inferior respect to `sysadmin`, maybe "on another server" you was granted any of the above.

If you are `local admin` on the pc where the server is installed, you always can run it in `single user mode` and become `sysadmin`: [Connect to SQL Server When System Administrators Are Locked Out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-2017)