# Multiple errors when using IIS

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, iis

I`m recently done my dating app project using angular asp.net-core and SQLserver, and I try to publish the project to IIS.

When I run the project locally all the requests get the desirable responses and it work just fine,but when I open the website from IIS server the app is work fine but any request get back the 500 code response.
After setting stdoutLogEnabled to "true" in my web.config file,I have seen there were multiple errors:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]

      Failed executing DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']

      CREATE DATABASE [Datingapp];

fail: DatingApp.API.Program[0]

      An error occured during migration

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String methodName)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Create()

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)

   at DatingApp.API.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\igala\OneDrive\????? ??????\DatingApp\datingapp.api\Program.cs:line 30

ClientConnectionId:e33b0290-928d-45a2-945f-8df556ac1f9a

Error Number:262,State:1,Class:14

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Hosting environment: Production

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]

      Content root path: C:\Users\igala\OneDrive\????? ??????\DatingAppIIS

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]

      An error occurred using the connection to database 'Datingapp' on server 'LAPTOP-JPCIFMKV\SQLEXPRESS'.

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]

      An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'DatingApp.API.Data.DataContext'.

      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "Datingapp" requested by the login. The login failed.

      Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\dating app'.

         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)

         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

      ClientConnectionId:3073436f-dbc0-45c1-8f1d-aa0050e5ba73

      Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "Datingapp" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\dating app'.

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

ClientConnectionId:3073436f-dbc0-45c1-8f1d-aa0050e5ba73

Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]

      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "Datingapp" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\dating app'.

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at DatingApp.API.Data.AuthRepository.Login(String username, String password) in C:\Users\igala\OneDrive\????? ??????\DatingApp\datingapp.api\Data\AuthRepository.cs:line 23

   at DatingApp.API.Controllers.AuthController.Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto) in C:\Users\igala\OneDrive\????? ??????\DatingApp\datingapp.api\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 54

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

ClientConnectionId:3073436f-dbc0-45c1-8f1d-aa0050e5ba73

Error Number:4060,State:1,Class:11

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[3]

      An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.

System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid control character in header: 0x0D

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.ValidateHeaderCharacters(String headerCharacters)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.ValidateHeaderCharacters(StringValues headerValues)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpSys.Internal.HeaderCollection.Add(String key, StringValues value)

   at DatingApp.API.Helpers.Extensions.AddApplicationError(HttpResponse response, String message) in C:\Users\igala\OneDrive\????? ??????\DatingApp\datingapp.api\Helpers\Extensions.cs:line 13

   at DatingApp.API.Startup.<>c.<<Configure>b__5_3>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\igala\OneDrive\????? ??????\DatingApp\datingapp.api\Startup.cs:line 72

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.HandleException(HttpContext context, ExceptionDispatchInfo edi)

fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpServer[2]

      Connection ID "18302628887244308495", Request ID "80000010-0000-fe00-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "Datingapp" requested by the login. The login failed.

Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\dating app'.

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)

   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.SingleOrDefaultAsync[TSource](IAsyncEnumerable`1 asyncEnumerable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

   at DatingApp.API.Data.AuthRepository.Login(String username, String password) in C:\Users\igala\OneDrive\????? ??????\DatingApp\datingapp.api\Data\AuthRepository.cs:line 23

   at DatingApp.API.Controllers.AuthController.Login(UserForLoginDto userForLoginDto) in C:\Users\igala\OneDrive\????? ??????\DatingApp\datingapp.api\Controllers\AuthController.cs:line 54

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

   at Mic
```

Seems the all the error bind to ef and it cant connect to sqlserver (the authentication is windows based if it matter...) ,as I said locally it work fine.

**web.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\DatingApp.API.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

- .NET hosting IIS is installed and up to date.

any ideas?

Comment: Your user  'IIS APPPOOL\dating app'. failed to login and connect to the DB. So setup the credentials to it can have access.

Comment: thank for the quick response, can you guide me how can I configure that user credentials ?@abestrad

Comment: @IgalAchourov Do you have command line (or PowerShell) access on the server? [osql Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/osql-utility?view=sql-server-ver15); [SQL-Server - Grant user DBO permission on database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/54389/143697). You would probably want to set the permissions back to "normal" afterwards for security.

Answer (score 0):

The connecting string is pointing to a wrong database or the application pool identity which is used to connect to the database does not have enough permissions to access the database.

try to set the application pool identity to the custom account which has full permission to access the SQL server database(admin user).

Give them a Server Roles that will give them credentials to create a database. set the db_owner and public.

refer this below link for more detail:

[CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master' (EF code-first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231934/create-database-permission-denied-in-database-master-ef-code-first)

Comment: I though the error came from the windows authentication, I tried now to connect to the db via user I created with all the permissions but yet no success. the connection string is fine because locally it work, maybe in the web.config file I need to specify the path?(the web.config file is shown in the post).

Answer (score 0):

Guys thank you all for the help problem solved, its first time I using IIS for publishing and the problem was in the application pool identity as you said but also in the site where "Physical Path Credentials" need to be specified.

Comment: if your issue is resolved I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer it will help other people who face similar issues.