# Changing connection string after moving database to App_Data folder?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I am trying  to learn mvc.net. I created a small project in which I used Model first approach. The problem is I wanted my database to be shown in App_data folder for that I followed this article:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2182/how-to-embed-sql-database-in-appdata-folder

In short I detached the database and then I include the database  in app_data folder. Now I am facing problem in changing the connection string, Previously I generated connection  string automatically using entity framework, It was like:

```
<add name="KeepitrememberEntities" 
connectionString="metadata=res://*/EDM.csdl|res://*/EDM.ssdl|res://*/EDM.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
data source=mypcname\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Keepitremember;
integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

and now I changed it to:

```
<add name="KeepitrememberEntities"
connectionString="Data Source=mypcname\SQLEXPRESS;
AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Keepitremember.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
User Instance=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I am executing the code and trying to save the value using a form, it's showing me the error in **EDM.Context.cs** and error is:

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.UnintentionalCodeFirstException'
>   occurred in Emptymvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First
>   and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code
>   First mode. To continue using Database First or Model First ensure
>   that the Entity Framework connection string is specified in the config
>   file of executing application. To use these classes, that were
>   generated from Database First or Model First, with Code First add any
>   additional configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API
>   and then remove the code that throws this exception.

What I need to do now, any solution!!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, the first connection string is Entity Framework connection string, and the second one is SQL Express connection string. In an EF project, both of them should be exist in `web.config` file for `DbContext` and code generation template usage - hence they're not interchangeable (i.e. you should not change EF connection string into SQL Express one and vice versa).

Since you have changed EF connection string contained CSDL, SSDL & MSL information required by EF into SQL Express one, EF assumes the existing database metadata isn't exist anymore and trying to create a new database like Code First has, hence it triggers `UnintentionalCodeFirstException` after executing `OnModelCreating` method.

Instead of changing EF connection string in `web.config`, just **add** SQL Express connection string on the same `connectionStrings` element as this (you may need to define initial catalog name when required):

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- SQL Express connection string -->
    <add name="KeepitrememberConnection"
    connectionString="Data Source=mypcname\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Keepitremember;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|Keepitremember.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
    User Instance=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

    <!-- EF connection string -->
    <add name="KeepitrememberEntities" 
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/EDM.csdl|res://*/EDM.ssdl|res://*/EDM.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;
    data source=mypcname\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Keepitremember;
    integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

NB: The connection string names should be **same** with predefined names in EF model generation schema.

Related issues:

[Model First with DbContext, Fails to initialize new DataBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940616/model-first-with-dbcontext-fails-to-initialize-new-database)

[Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703099/code-generated-using-the-t4-templates-for-database-first-and-model-first-develop)

[Entity Framework cant use the DbContext, model being created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944596/entity-framework-cant-use-the-dbcontext-model-being-created)