# How to prevent EF6 from creating method OnModelCreating (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm new to EF, so I need your support. Every time I actualize my EF Model from database (Database First), EF creates the method "OnModelCreating":

```
Namespace FDB.Model

Partial Public Class FDBEntities
    Inherits DbContext

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New("name=FDBEntities")
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        Throw New UnintentionalCodeFirstException()
    End Sub
```

In this method, the "UnintentionalCodeFirstException" will be thrown. How can I prevent EF from creating this exception? Everytime I change this method, EF of course will override it when the model is actualized. I already created a second class "Partial Public FDBEntities" with a "On ModelCreating"-method in it, but that won't work:

```
Partial Public Class FDBEntities
    Inherits DbContext

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
    End Sub
End Class
```

After actualizing the EDM, this method will be underlined red, because there already exists a method with identical signature.

FYI: Initially I indeed use Code First, but I completely removed the Datalayer (folders and files) and create a new one with Database First, so I think, this cannot be the reason for this exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5942978/2319909

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model First with DbContext, Fails to initialize new DataBase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940616/model-first-with-dbcontext-fails-to-initialize-new-database)